# How to find days elapsed between an order

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How do I find the days elapsed between each menu item being ordered from this set of data:

```
account    menuItem       beginDate      endDate
'123'      'I1'           '2016-01-10'   '2016-01-16'
'145'      'I1'           '2016-03-11'   '2016-03-26'
'156'      'I2'           '2016-02-10'   '2016-02-26'
```

I have this query so far:

```
Select  menuItem, Datediff(day, beginDay, endDay) DaysOrdered
From MealCheckout
Group By menuItem
Order By beginDate, endDate
```

So the output should be for example for `menuItem I1` there are two records. So it should take the start date of the first record which is `'2016-01-10'` and the end date of the last occurrence of an `I1` record which is the second record and take the `endDate` from that last record which is `'2016-03-26'` and subtract the `startDate` and `endDate` to find the elapsed time. The above query doesn't work, it doesn't output any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract dates in Oracle to get the elapsed days.  So:

```
Select menuItem, max(endDay) - min(beginDay) DaysOrdered
From MealCheckout
Group By menuItem;
```

Your query should return an error in Oracle; there is no `datediff()` function.

Comment: Thank you this was the correct query! I was not aware there is no datediff() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select menuItem,
  max(to_date(endDay,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-min(to_date(beginDay,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
  From MealCheckout
  Group By menuItem;
```